# Ruby random selection from array sometimes returns same value repeatedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, random

I am using this to select a random Matchup, and I test it's results, and draw a random Matchup until it meets the criteria of a `while` loop:

```
m = Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first
```

The loop is set to `break` after 10 cycles (to avoid infinite loops), and I will arbitrarily break out of the loop, check the logs, and see that the Matchup is the same every time it went through the loop. A simplified version of the loop would be something like this:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 5
    m = Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first
    logger.debug('Matchup ID: ' + m.id)
    counter += 1
end
```

The log will look like this:

```
Matchup ID: 7
Matchup ID: 7
Matchup ID: 7
Matchup ID: 7
Matchup ID: 7
```

Why would `m = Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first` arbitrarily not pull a different Matchup? The strangest part is that sometimes it works without issue, and others it gets stuck in the loop b/c `m` is not changing. Any suggestions?

If you want to see the actual loop, you can see it here (in the `getRandomMatchup` function): 
    https://github.com/jackerman09/wdis/blob/master/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

Comment: Maybe in that case there's just one `Matchup` in the database?

Comment: Do you mean `RAND()` instead of `RANDOM()`?  See http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random

Comment: @Davidann in PostgreSQL it's `RANDOM()`.

Comment: Instead of a `while` loop, why don't you just select 5 records in random order and loop over them? `Matchup.order("RANDOM()").first(5).each ...`

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: @stefan, there are hundreds of Matchups in the database. I am sure of this because when I refresh the page, the matchup will be different from the previous time, but within the loop, the Matchup stays the same.

Comment: A problem with using a "random" value, is that we can get repeated occurrences of the same value. That's the nature of randomness. If you need to shuffle a set of values and then extract them sequentially, it's a different problem and solution.

Comment: In this case though, the failure is too low probability to be seeing it frequently in tests. Instead I would expect the query cache is involved. There is probably some syntax to tell Postgres to not use it.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I'm not familiar with the query cache. Where do I address this issue?

Comment: Or perhaps the Active Record cache (rather than Postgres).

Comment: @matt, any suggestion on how I can see/change this cache? I'm still pretty new to ruby/rails. Thanks again

Comment: @jackerman09 I don’t really know Rails myself, but maybe this: https://coderwall.com/p/tvybhq

Comment: I've just been researching "query_cache" and Postgres doesn't have one (whereas MySQL does). However, there may be other ways in which the data is cached here.

Comment: @matt, that looks like a good resource, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add another variant :)

```
ids = Matchup.pluck(:id)
m = Matchup.find( ids.shuffle.first )
```

This will work well unless the set of `id` values is excessive, in which case you are shuffling a very large array. However, in the 1k to 2k set size, it will not be noticeable to a user.

Or simply:

```
ids = Matchup.pluck(:id)
m = Matchup.find( ids.sample )
```

Will choose a random item from the `ids` array.

Comment: IMO, doing `ids.shuffle.first` is much clearer than `ids[rand(ids.length)]`.:) Gold star for you.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois indeed, the old cleanliness/speed trade-off :)

Comment: Does pluck insure that I will only get an ID for which a Matchup exists?

Comment: @mbratch yes :) but here we might want to giveup on clean code since it will strongly depend on the `ids` size :-/

Comment: There will probably be 1k-2k Matchups in the database. Would this cause you to recommend against your solution?

Comment: @jackerman09 you could try this or Davidann's second solution that uses `pluck`. Functionally they're the same. With 1-2k matchups, I suspect a user wouldn't notice the difference.

Comment: @mbratch, will ActiveRecord's cache cause this to return the same result every time the query is run if the cache is not disabled?

Comment: @mbratch can you maybe edit your answer and warn users about the potential issue regarding the `ids` size?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois got it.

Comment: `m = Matchup.find( ids.sample )`

Comment: @mbratch, I tried implementing your suggestion, and I'm still seeing the same result over and over. Does it matter that I am reaching the controller via an AJAX call? When the page is fully refreshed it works correctly. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @jackerman09 somehow it is perhaps only seeing one record and therefore only producing one result. In that case can you peek at the record count and the collection of id's it thinks are in the collection? It does indeed seem that the AJAX call is impacting it somehow.

Comment: @mbratch, I know that I can do this via the debugger or logger in development, but how can I check this in production? Thanks again

Comment: @jackerman09 are you saying that this all works in development mode but not production? Does the development mode use AJAX? For production, you could either log the information and look at the `production.log` file, or, if you're not in a live user situation, display the info right on the screen of the web page using `<%= ...%>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this model is a normal ActiveRecord model, You could try something like:

```
max_id = Matchup.maximum(:id)
id = rand(max_id)
m = Matchup.find(id)
...
```

Doing so might be cheaper than asking the database to get you randomly ordered records.  However, the downside of this approach is that records may be deleted, so `Matchup.find(id)` may be `nil`.

Another, better, way to do this might be:

```
ids = Matchup.pluck(:id)
m = Matchup.find(ids[rand(ids.length)])
```

Comment: This assumes there are no missing ids in the database.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: You are correct.  I point that out in my answer and then give a better answer.

Comment: @mcfinnigan, good point. There are many IDs in the database for which no Matchup exists, so this wouldn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use shuffle for this:-

```
Matchup.all.shuffle!.first
```

Comment: This is clean and concise, but it does fetch all of the records to do it. I think @Davidann has a good idea to avoid fetching all of the data.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why my above code was not working (sometimes)?

Comment: Well that's strange, I tried it in my local and random function is giving random values to me :)

Comment: @NikitaSingh, it works fine locally for me, too (my original design worked locally), but when deployed (on Heroku), it becomes a problem.